# OpenLayers : Can I give marker a name, description?

Tags: openlayers, marker

With this http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Text-js.html one can load from file markers with name and description. Can one create markers with description without loading them from  saved file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by yourself.
Openlayers doesn't support this